# Django 1.9 list_filter

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.9

I have these models

```
class Team(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class Course(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=500)
    directory = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Directory', null=True, verbose_name='Directory')
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Team', through='myapp.TeamCourse')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class TeamCourse(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Course')
    team = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Team')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team.description


class Directory(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=500)
    sector = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Sector')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class Sector(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

and this admin

```
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'description')
    list_filter = ('course', 'course__directory', 'course__directory__sector')
    search_fields = ('id', 'course',)
    list_display_icons = True
    list_per_page = 15
    export_to_xls = True
admin.site.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```

The problem occurs when I try to access the list_filter 'course__directory__sector' (http://localhost:8000/admin/myapp/team/?course__directory__sector__id__exact=1) in the django 1.9. This worked until django 1.7. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is.

Comment: `max_length` of `CharField` is 255, cause it is VARCHAR.

Comment: Your question's title doesn't help. Please edit it to something more clear.